# Getting an array from folder and sending a random file with discord.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm trying to create a command, when requested will send a random image from a folder. I don't want to have to name them cause I have a server with a PHP server where my friends can upload images for the bot to post. This is what I have:

```
 if(command === "meme") {
      const path = '/img/memes/';
      const fs = require('fs');

      fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {
          ranfile = Math.floor(Math.random()*file.length);
          message.channel.sendFile(ranfile);
      })

      return;
 }
```

When I run the bot with Node.js I get this error:

```
(node:4840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: please add try catch or handle promise rejections.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably just a regular error wrapped in an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.  Have you tried running with `--trace-warnings`?
This should solve the problem of getting to the actual issue by providing a reasonable stack trace.

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help :)