# How can I easily access the pictures of a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was commissioned to make a new Discord bot that does a list of things. One thing they wanted it to do was post a random picture from a folder they provided me with over 100 pictures. I really do not feel like storing all of those directories in an array, as that would take forever to type. Is there an easier way to access and randomly select an image to send without doing this?

```
let images = ["./pictures/image1.jpeg",, "./pictures/image2.jpeg", ....];
let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
message.channel.send({files: [picture[index]]});
```

The code above is what I am currently using and I have to add another 100 pictures to the array and I really do not want to type their directories all out.If you need to know the discord bot library it is discord.js. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851030/getting-an-array-from-folder-and-sending-a-random-file-with-discord-js/50851251](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50851030/getting-an-array-from-folder-and-sending-a-random-file-with-discord-js/50851251)

Comment: I think this might work. Thank you for this info.

Answer (score 1):

This function might work for you:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function randomFile(){
    const image_directory = './images/';
    let files = fs.readdirSync(image_directory).map(file => {
        return file;
    });

    return files[Math.floor(Math.random() * files.length)];
}

console.log(randomFile());
```

Comment: I am getting an error. "Cannot create property 'name' on number '3'". I am assuming this has everything to do with the file names they provided me?

Comment: I think you are trying get absolute file path instead of filename? right?